# foreach on null throws error since migration to Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony

I migrated my web application from Symfony 2 to 3. Since then whenever a foreach loop is executed on null, an error is thrown ("Invalid argument").

Example:

```
$myResults = null;

foreach ($myResults as $item) {
   // do something
}
```

How do I achieve that as before no error is thrown?

Comment: As far as I can see, no PHP version >= 5.5 would have supported `null` here. The Symfony version is only relevant if they changed the return value of something that you're iterating over from iterable value with no content to null.

Comment: you can check before foreach. 
`if(is_null($myResults)){}`

Comment: Have you upgraded PHP version as well? This sounds like it is caused by one of the language changes in PHP 7.1 or 7.2

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug introduced by an upgrade to a newer PHP version (7.1+).

You can verify this by executing your code sample in an interactive php shell without any Symfony code being loaded:

```
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > $var = null;
php > foreach ($var as $v) {}
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in php shell code on line 1
```

You can also verify this on [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/7WX2D)

In order to fix this you have to check for null before looping or (temporarily) go back to an older (unsupported!) PHP version. Depending on how well your code is typed there are some static code analysis tools, that will help you finding the loops you will have to safeguard.